# how can i add backgrounds and animate them in blender 2.80 2d animation?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, 2d

Im making a 2d animation and added a background but the background doesn't appear in the render and neither in the frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added it in as a reference image, that might be problem. Try adding a plane in the back and add the background on that. You can do that in the material options.

Comment: thanks it works in the beginning but in a new file when i add image as a plane the plane is grey and doesn't show the image

Comment: Try adding a lamp to light up the background.

Comment: thanks! it worked, it turns out that i need to see it as a material .

Comment: How do I add a plane in the back? I'm the most novice a user can be.