# How can I upload my own image as a background image and texture to a 2D animation in Blender 2.8?

Tags: animation, texturing, image, 2d

Although this was been asked and answered [before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156096/how-can-i-add-backgrounds-and-animate-them-in-blender-2-80-2d-animation), I still do not understand the process. I am a complete novice- this is my first day using Blender for 2D animation. I don't know how to upload my own images to materials/textures or how to add a plane. I am struggling to find a straight forward answer here, and I've been looking for about an hour now. Please let me know what is the best way to upload my own image as a background AND texture for 2d animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is relatively straight forward, but can be made easier by enabling a built in add-on for blender called "Images as planes". Go to User Preferences > Addons and search in the box for images - only one result should pop up -"Import/Export: Import Images as Planes". Check the box and exit user preferences.

[image: ImagesPlane]

Hover your mouse over the viewport you are using and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. Select image and then image as plane. A box will pop up letting you select you photo from your PC. Pick the image you want. If instead, you are looking to use a background image, pick "Background", the rest is the same.

[image: ImagePlane2]

Lastly, to see the image, select one of the rendered mode tabs - either Material Preview or Rendered Preview.

[image: ImagePlane3]

This is the 3D viewport in the 2D animation tab. To add an image you have to be in object mode. But what happens when you press shift+a, are you saying nothing happens? If so, have you changed any of your shortcuts/hotkeys? You can also access it from the menu at the top. See image:

[image: 2Danimation]

Comment: This looks like it will work, but I am unable to get the "add" menu when pushing Shift+A. I am in 2-D animation, 3D Viewport, and Edit mode if that helps.

Comment: I edited my answer with some more info. Let me know if that helps. If there is no "Add" option at the top, there must be something else going on.

Comment: I could only bring up the "Add" menu in "object mode" within the 2D animation part of Blender. Thank you for your help! Now I just need to save the video somehow :P

Comment: Also, thanks for the plethora of screenshots. That was really helpful, and I appreciate the amount of time you put into helping me. You're awesome!

Comment: Hey, no problem - it's all a process. Soon you'll be a whiz.

Comment: Thank you for your welcoming hand!

Comment: Just a side question: when I render the animation, the background picture is not in the final file, yet it is showing in my viewpoint just fine. How do I include the background photo in the final rendering?

Comment: I see now that adding an image as a background is only for reference in the viewpoint, so I added the image as a plane. That resolved the issue!